# Use UserDefaults to store data for different users

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save data of two different users in my iOS app. I did managed to save login and profile details of two or more users in android using the Sharedpreferences like this.

`getSharedPreferences (String FIRST_USER, int mode)
getSharedPreferences (String SECOND_USER, int mode)
...`

And with this approch I will just check the `userid` of current user and load `SharedPrefs` file at startup and then read data from `current_users sharedPref` file  using the same `KEY - VALUE` pairs. And when user is switched, just load the different file and everything will be changed.

I know that UserDefaults is equivalent of sharedprefs in iOS but i don't know if
I can do something similar to what I did in android with different SharedPrefs Files.

Don't have any high experience in iOS programming.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide in which type of user data is available?

Comment: use NSArchiever

Comment: @Jaydeep it will be simple StringValues some parameters for APIs like userid,name,mobnum etc.

Comment: @Shezad can you please tell a bit more about NSArchiever and how I can use it to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Use the below method to get path for saving your data:

```
func filePath(key:String) -> String {
    let manager = FileManager.default
    let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    return (url!.appendingPathComponent(key).path)
}
```

2.Store your data using the following code:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data, toFile: filePath(key: "anyKey"))
```

3.Fetch the data you saved using the following code:

```
if let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile:filePath(key:"anyKey")) {
       //here you will get your data
       print(data)
}
```

Note: use the same key here which you used for storing data

Comment: thanks for the details.. i can create the file with this code but when i try to store and the print the data, i don't get anything. may b i'm misunderstanding the `data` thingy.. can you please comment on this? I'm using it like this. to create file -> `filePath(key:"MyFileName")`.. to store data 
 -> NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject("MY STRING", toFile: filePath(key: "MyFileName"))`.. to print data -> `let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile:filePath(key:"MyFileName")) . print (data)`

Comment: it won't print for the first time. first you have to store the data then try to print
use the same key for both

Comment: @Joe it works fine for me. can u share the code how you are using it???